# run second mysql instance on a different port

Tags: mysql

I already have a mysqld running on port 3306 on my linux system and want a second instance on a different port. This is a totally different instance, I don't want it to share data tables or anything else with the first instance. I tried running mysqld --defaults-file=config.conf where config.conf is my other config file with the new port and datadir, tried using absolute paths, everything, and kept getting this error: Could not open required defaults file: /PATH_TO_FILE/config.conf
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Can anyone please help me? Everything about --defaults-file I find is about windows, how do I specify a custom config file on linux? Or is it possible to use the --datadir command line option (is there a command line option to specify the port also?) and would that create a totally unrelalted instance of mysqld?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to run a separate instance of mysqld?

Comment: Not sure if this helps or hinders his case, but it's a fairly standard practice in the MS SQL Server world; two disparate systems from different vendors that have no need to share data, and might be administered by different employees or supported by different third (fourth? fifth?) parties that don't need to play in each others' sandboxes. An example would be the payroll and patient-data systems in a healthcare environment.

Answer (score 2):

Does your path contain a tilde (~)? http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20597

Alternately, does the user MySQL runs as have permission to access the file?

Comment: Could SELINUX be blocking access?

Comment: I don't really know anything about SELinux. I just meant that if your config file isn't owned by mysql you might need to change the owner: `sudo chown mysql filename` (I don't actually know what user MySQL runs as on your system)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [mysql sandbox](http://mysqlsandbox.net/). it seems this might be a solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

are you providing the complete /path/to/config.conf ?